# Use Jquery load to refresh div then click a link before reshowing content

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im using the jquery load function to refresh the contents of a div.

I start by hiding the div

```
$('.dashboard-body').fadeOut(50);
```

Then ajax load - to refresh the content

After the load event and while the refreshed div is still hidden id like to click on one of the contents pagination links. Then when the div is shown again the correct content is shown.

Heres the code that doesnt work. Im using the livequery plugin as a listener for new elements in the DOM.

```
$('.dashboard-body').load(target, function(){
                $('.pagination ul li a').livequery(function(){
                    $(this).each(function(){
                        var target_page = $(this).html();
                        if(target_page == return_page){
                            $(this).click();
                        }
                    });
                });

                $('.dashboard-body').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                    //success
                });

            });
```

The code above in my mind does the following.

It loads the target page back into the div with class dashboard-body.

Its listens for new pagination links loaded into the dom using livequery

It then iterates over each link found

It finds the links numerical value ie. 1, 2, 3.... and defines as the a potential target page number.

Then if the target page and return page number (which is a predefined variable) are equal. Click this link.

It all seems to work and using the console i can see that this statement...

```
if(target_page == return_page){
```

is true once as expected but the click event wont happen as if the element doesnt exist but it should do as its just iterated over them.

I cant see whats wrong any ideas? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I made a test http://jsfiddle.net/y6yJN/ without .load — it works as expected, click handler does its job well at least in my browser. Also, I used .text() instead of .html() for getting a string number in a link.

My piece of markup

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#example">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#example2">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#example3">3</a>
        </li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

and its script:

```
var return_page = '2'; //some string

//click handler for links
$('.pagination ul li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});


//must alert '#example2' on page load
$('.pagination ul li a').each(function(){
    page_number = $(this).text();
    if(page_number === return_page){
        $(this).click();
    }
});
```

Also I think you do not need livequery or such for this since callback function is called after the DOM changed, making jQuery collection on new DOM already. I can be wrong at this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but without livequery the each loop doesnt find any of the elements. I have just tied it. My code works upto the code inside the IF statement. The click wont fire. However if i change click to addClass it works just fine.

Comment: Ok. Can you attach the markup of a single link that gets loaded into .pagination?

Comment: even without fadeOut and FadeIn just this code $('.dashboard-body').load(target, function(){
     //$('.dashboard-body').fadeIn('slow',function(){
      console.log($('.pagination ul li a:eq(1)').text());
         $('.pagination ul li:eq(1)').click();
        //});

    }); it doesnt work. The console returns an empty string

Comment: Could it be that click handler is not live-attached to loaded links? If there are no href attributes and no handlers, click() will do nothing visible, I think.

Comment: <a href="#">'+button_number+'</a> the links are dynamically generated

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add this code for the click event handler

```
$('body').on('click','.pagination ul li a',function(event){
```